# How to access a session variable via javascript in Classic Asp?

Tags: javascript, session, encryption, asp-classic

I  am trying to access a session variable in asp page, it does not work.
Here is my menu.htm file

```
<aside class="grid_1">
  <nav class="global">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li [wages] ><a  id="wages" class="nav-icon icon-email" href="">Wages</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
<script type='text/javascript'>

        alert("Company id ID " + <%=Session("company_id") %>);
         //it says syntax error  "here"
</script>
```

According to wayne's comment,

[image]

Comment: `menu.htm` doesn't look like asp file. change the extension to `menu.asp` and update references.

Comment: The syntax should be `alert("Company ID: <%=Session("company_id") %>");`

Comment: @WayneEllery Still there is an error saying ")" expected

Comment: Are you sure you used exactly what I typed? I just tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: Yep, that looks good. So what's the error? Is it a console error in the browser?

Comment: No in visual studio , Expected ')' . this is the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70501/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-wayne-ellery).

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
alert('Company ID: <%=Session("company_id")%>');
```

And yes **menu.htm** has to be an ASP file i.e. **menu.asp**, otherwise the code inside asp tag `<% %>` will not work, is not replaced with actual session value at server-side.

For example if session variable value is 456789 then asp tag will replace with this value at server-side like:

```
alert('Company ID: 456789');
```

and sent to client browser who requested this page.
and browser will treat it as plain java-script.
Thank you.